# Why I can't change the attendee's type in outlook with vbs?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I was doing a script to book meeting room automatically. But at the very last step, the AppointmentItem just cannot change to MeetingItem. Here is the code:

```vb
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(1)  
myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

myItem.Subject = "..."  
myItem.Location = "..."  
myItem.Start = #...#  
myItem.Duration = 90 

set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com")
myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource

myItem.Save
' myItem.Send
```

I believed that I alreday set the Recipient's type into "olResource", it's the same way according to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/items-folders-and-stores/create-an-appointment-as-a-meeting-on-the-calendar). But this is what I got:

The item in my calender shows it's still an [Appointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNFrt.png), and the resource I added is [Required Attendee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c6zo.jpg).

After I set it into Resource manually, then it become a [Meeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P30eZ.png). I dont undersand how this happened, and how I can solve this. Please help me! Many thanks!!

BTW, The outlook version is Outlook 2016 (16.0.4849.1000) 32-bit.

Comment: Did you try to use `Send` instead of `Save`?

Comment: Yes. Already did. But it's a Appointment, it can only be saved into my own calendar, it cannt be sent to anyone.

Comment: Are you using vba or vbscript? Those are two different languages, and the answer probably depends on that as well.

Comment: @Geert it's vbscript.

Comment: Then you don't need to add vba or outlook-vba tags

Comment: You haven't defined olMeeting or olResource. In outlook-vba these might be known values, but not in vbscript. You have to define values for them. Use `option explicit` above your code to get informed about such mistakes.

Comment: @Geert Oh! now I know why! but could you please tell me how to define olMeeting/olResource? Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook enumeration values such as `olMeeting` and `olResource` are not known in vbscript (as opposed to Outlook-VBA)

You first need to figure out their numerical value from the documentation.
For example the [OlMeetingStatus enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olmeetingstatus?view=outlook-pia) documentation says the following:

- olMeeting - 1 - The meeting has been scheduled.
- olMeetingCanceled - 5 - The scheduled meeting has been cancelled.
- olMeetingReceived - 3 - The meeting request has been received.
- olMeetingReceivedAndCanceled - 7 - The scheduled meeting has been cancelled but still appears on the user's calendar.
- olNonMeeting - 0 - An Appointment item without attendees has been scheduled. This status can be used to set up holidays on a calendar.

In vbscript you can then define your own constants to match the known enumeration values

```
const olMeeting = 1 '<- define enum value here

dim myItem
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(1)  
myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting '<- use it here just like you would in VBA
```

Comment: the documentation link you gave is so useful, I haven't noticed it before. Thank you so much.